# SharePoint Vacation Approval

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am just wondering would someone be able to give me a hand with an issue I am having.

I have created a vacation approval using a copy of the OOB Vacation Approval workflow. I have a few issues that I cant seem to address.

The Vacation is initiated, the first stage of the Approval goes to the direct manager and once approved will go to the HR manger. I have achieved this by adding a second stage approver.

This is working fine but I would like to change a few things. For the first approval, I am only able to add a group or single person, as many people will have a different value for this I am wondering is it possible to take a value from the list and add it to this point of the work flow instead of adding a set group.

A second problem I would like to address is in the approval workflow there is an option to CC, I would like to CC pay-role but only after the second HR approver, does anyone know if this is possible.

Finally I would like information that the first approver enters into the form to be saved for the second approver to be able to read within the same form and for them to check the values they need to check on it before approving it. Is this possible?

Thanks